# How does the notation of limits read in plain English? (3)

Tags: limits, notation

How does the following notation read in plain English:

I can't interpret it myself.

$$a^+ = \lim\limits_{0 < \epsilon \to 0} a + \epsilon$$

Ref. *[Hwei Hsu. Page-39. ... (B) Properties of  $F_{X}(x)$](https://www.dca.ufrn.br/~affonso/FTP/livros/Hsu_probabilidade.pdf)*

Comment: The limit of $a+\epsilon$ as $\epsilon$ approaches zero from the right.

Comment: also written as $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to0^+}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $0<\epsilon\to 0$ says "epsilon, greater than zero, approaches 0."

Epsilon is approaching 0, and at the same time, epsilon is always positive.  We could also say epsilon is approaching 0 "from the right" as this is how we visualize it on the number line.

This line is introducing the notation $0^+$ (or $a^+$) as $\epsilon \to 0^+$ is less clunky to write.

Answer (score 1):

$0 < \epsilon \to 0$ in the subscript means $\epsilon$ approaches $0$ from the right, so, as already mentioned, this reads as "the limit of $a + \epsilon$ as $\epsilon$ approaches $0$ from the right".

Comment: why is 0< e->0?

Comment: It's just the notation for $\epsilon$ approaching $0$ from the right. Since you want to approach it from the right, then $\epsilon > 0$, and since you're approaching $0$, we can just write $0 < \epsilon \to 0$